# JavaScript Asynchronous Function Woe

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise

Suppose I have a web application returning exchange rate for given currency pair at `/exchange_rate/ccy1/ccy2`, whenever the currency pair is not found in the database, the web app returns 404.

In the front-end JavaScript code, to be fail-safe, whenever local exchange rate query fails, I'll then query a public provider, say currencyconverterapi.com

Let's also assume for some reason (the actual code uses Vue lifecycle hooks), **the global variable `rate`, and the two functions can't be merged and can't be made into async**.

The problem with the following code is it only works when local query `axios.get('/exchange_rate/EUR/' + ccy)` resolves; when it rejects, the `amount * rate` will execute before `axios.get('http://free.currencyconverterapi.com...)` sets `rate` --

```
var rate;

function getExchangeRate(ccy) {
    return axios.get('/exchange_rate/EUR/' + ccy)
    .then(ret => {
        rate = ret.data.rate;
    }).catch(err => {
        axios.get('http://free.currencyconverterapi.com/api/v5/convert?q=EUR_' 
        + ccy).then(ret => {
            rate = ret.data.results.val;
        });
    });
}

function toEUR(ccy, amount) {
    getExchangeRate(ccy)
    .then(() => {
        return amount * rate;
    });
}

var EURAmount = toEUR('USD', 42);
```

My question is: is there a way to guarantee `rate` is properly set by `getExchangeRate` in `toEUR`?

Comment: You could check the value of rate in the .then() of toEUR() and if it is not set correctly, do a recursive call of toEUR(), else return.

Comment: `toEUR()` doesn't return your promise. There are a few bad practices in your code, e.g. nesting a promise in another promise, and using a global updated asynchronously. The two functions don't need to be merged, just chained properly with `.then()`.

Comment: Have `toEUR` check if `rate===undefined`, and return an empty value if so. Assuming toEUR is a Vue computed value, and `rate` is a data field on the component, it'll automatically run again when `rate` changes.

Comment: **...the two functions can't be merged and can't be made into async can't be made into async** - then perhaps the return value should't depend on a value that can only be returned via an asynchronous call? The answer to this question is just like all the similar questions - change the way your code works so it's asynchronous, that, and as @PatrickRoberts said, you need to return the Promise from `toEUR` - `return getExchangeRate(ccy)...`

Comment: Thanks everyone for your valuable input. Just wish to clarify more on the seemingly convoluted use of global variable and the two functions for any future visitors -- the snippet here is not a literal copy of the actual code, which uses Vue. "rate" is a Vue data variable, getExchangeRate() is one of the Vue methods, and toEUR() is a beforeMount hook function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `then` in your `toEUR` function is not waiting for the second request to complete because you are not `return`ing in the `catch`.

You should also not be using shared state for the `rate` variable. Just return it as the result of your promise.

```
function getExchangeRate(ccy) {
    return axios.get('/exchange_rate/EUR/' + ccy)
    .then(ret => ret.data.rate)
    .catch(err => {
        return axios.get('http://free.currencyconverterapi.com/api/v5/convert?q=EUR_' 
        + ccy)
            .then(ret => ret.data.results.val);
    });
}

function toEUR(ccy, amount) {
    return getExchangeRate(ccy)
        .then(rate => amount * rate);
}

toEUR('USD', 42)
    .then(amount => console.log(amount))
    .catch(err => console.error(err));
```

I would advise factoring out the backup call as a separate function so you don't have nested promises:

```
function getExchangeRatePublicProvider(ccy) {
    return axios.get('http://free.currencyconverterapi.com/api/v5/convert?q=EUR_' 
        + ccy)
        .then(ret => ret.data.results.val);
}

function getExchangeRate(ccy) {
    return axios.get('/exchange_rate/EUR/' + ccy)
        .then(ret => ret.data.rate)
        .catch(err => getExhangeRatePublicProvider(ccy));
}

function toEUR(ccy, amount) {
    return getExchangeRate(ccy)
        .then(rate => amount * rate);
}

toEUR('USD', 42)
    .then(amount => console.log(amount))
    .catch(err => console.error(err));
```

Comment: Perfect answer. This covers all the issues I mentioned in [my comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50861492/javascript-asynchronous-function-woe#comment88725570_50861492) and then some.